# Why it is so hard to find a prime of the form $a^b+b\cdot c+c^d$?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Why it is so hard to find a prime $p$ of the form:

$a^b+b\cdot c+c^d$?

where $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are four consecutive primes $a<b<c<d$?
Can such a prime exist?

Comment: Why is it hard? What did you try?

Comment: Perhaps it is hard because you put a lot of constraints on the prime in question. Perhaps if you relaxed to the case where $a, b, c, d$ are just any primes, or even the case where $a, b, c, d$ are just any number it would become easier? (Of course, if it stays hard even in the more permissive cases, that would only yield an even more interesting question. So it is worth checking, if you haven't already.)

Comment: @Vincent I am checking with Pfgw but no solution

Comment: What about $a = b = d = 2$, $c = 3$? Not to mention $a = b = 2$, $c = d = 3$ and $a = b = 3, c = 5, d = 2$...

Comment: You mean there are no solution with $a, b, c, d$ *distinct*? I didn't try that

Comment: @Vincent yes distinct they are consecutive primes

Comment: Yes, Ok, but I was interested in the slightly different question of whether finding solutions is already hard if we weaken the condition of being consecutive primes, or that with any weakening it suddenly becomes easy. Maybe the first thing to try is the case where $a, b, c, d$ are distinct, but not necessarily consecutive primes.

Comment: Is there any reason to care whether there is a prime of such an unmotivated form?

Answer (score 10):

It is easy to answer your first question at least heuristically, while I don't know the answer to your second question.

If we denote $p:=a$ (so that $p$ is a prime and $b,c,d$ are the next three primes), then your sum exceeds $p^p$, so heuristically you have a chance of less than $1/(p\log p)$ for it to be prime. However, the sum of $1/(p\log p)$ over all primes $p$ converges, so the [Borel-Cantelli lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma) suggests that there are only finitely many $p$'s for which your sum is prime.